# How to make canvas with Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java-canvas

I'm trying to make a paint editor with Java in which I have a toolbar with the objects that I would like to paste in the canvas. I'm using Swing components to make the GUI, but when I looked for the way of making the canvas, I only found the class canvas from AWT.

Is there any way to make something similar to canvas with Swing? (for example, JPanel?) I have read that using the class canvas from AWT with a GUI made with swing won't work correctly, is that true?

Answer (score 49):

In order to make a custom 'Canvas' in swing you usually write a subclass of a [`JPanel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).  Then, you must overwrite the `protected paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of `JPanel`.

In the paint method, you can call methods on the [`Graphics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object to actually draw on the `JPanel`.

As always, the Java Tutorials have a [great reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) on this to get you started.

Comment: Very useful! I didn't know that a JPanel could be so multiverse. :-)

Answer (score 20):

You'll probably want to make a subclass of [`JPanel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and implement your own way of painting components you want to draw onto the panel.

The basic approach will probably be along the line of assigning a [`MouseListener`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to the subclass of `JPanel`, then implement painting functionality.

The basic idea may be something along the line of:

```
class MyCanvas extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    Image img;      // Contains the image to draw on MyCanvas

    public MyCanvas()
    {
        // Initialize img here.
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        // Draws the image to the canvas
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
        g.fillOval(x, y, 3, 3);
        g.dispose();
    }

    // ... other MouseListener methods ... //
}
```

The above example is incomplete (and not tested -- it definitely won't compile), but it gives an idea about how to implement a `MyCanvas` class in which a user can click on and draw circles.

The `img` object is used to hold the image of the canvas. The `paintComponent` method is used to paint the `img` object to the canvas. In the `mouseClicked` method, the `Graphics` object associated with `img` is retrieved in order to `fillOval` onto the image.

Since one the requirements is to paste images onto the canvas, it may be a good idea to hold some `Image`s that you want to paste into the canvas. Perhaps something along the line of:

```
Image[] myImages;    // Used to store images to paint to screen.
```

Then, in the routine to paint the image onto `img` stored in `MyCanvas`:

```
g.drawImage(myImage[INDEX_OF_DESIRED_IMAGE], 0, 0, null);
```

By using the [`drawImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) method of the [`Graphics`](http://java.sun.com//javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) object, other `Image`s can be drawn onto `Image`s.

---

As for the question on AWT and Swing, yes, it is true that you do not want to mix components from the AWT and Swing, as they differ in the way they render GUI components. AWT is based on heavyweight components, meaning they native windowing for painting the GUI, while Swing is based on lightweight components, meaning the GUI is drawn by Java itself without using native components.

A good guide on the difference of AWT and Swing is provided in [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) article from Sun.

Comment: URL's have changed since 2009. Found actual location of article at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html

Answer (score 14):

Simply subclass `JComponent`.

`JPanel` is an inappropriate class. It is often suggested as it appears to have `setOpaque(true)` invoked on it automatically. It's actually the PL&F which does that, and whether or not it actually happens is implementation and vendor dependent.

`Canvas` is a heavyweight component. That is to say that it is controlled by the underlying windowing system. The result is that it will typically be drawn over the top of Swing components, without respect to z-order or clipping (putting it in a scroll pane will give odd behaviour).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the Minueto API. It is a very simple to use graphics api, and you can combine the Java event listening with it to provide your drawing capability.

http://minueto.cs.mcgill.ca/