# Creating custom components in Java AWT

Tags: java, awt

I am trying to create a custom component using Java AWT or Swing which will be a rectangle with a number of components inside of it, including other rectangles. Something like this:

```
╔══════╗
║  ┌┐  ║
║  ├┘  ║
║      ║
╚══════╝
```

And this needs to be a component that I can preferably draw with one instruction. Something like `myFrame.add(new MyComponent())`.

What would you say is the best way to do this? Is there a way I can do this using `Rectangle`, or should I go with `JPanel` or something from Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend extending a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent()` method.  See [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776180/how-to-make-canvas-with-swing/776215#776215) for some help on that.

Basically, when a rectangle is 'drawn' on your panel, you will want to save it as a member of the `Jpanel`.  Then, in the `paintComponent` method, you will just draw all of the rectangles you have saved in your `JPanel`.

This is how I would implement a 'draw' method:

```
List<Rectangle> recs;
List<Stroke> strokes;
List<Color> colors;
public void drawRectangle(Rectangle newR, Stroke stroke, Color c){
    recs.add(newR);
    strokes.add(stroke);
    colors.add(c);
}
```

And, the paint component will look similar to:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (int i = 0; i < recs.size(); i ++) {
        g.setColor(colors.get(i));
        g.setStroke(strokes.get(i));
        g.drawRectangle(recs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

"a number of components" -> JPanel with a layout manager to place each component

"draw" -> override paint on component

Check the Java Tutorial Swing section.