# Dont know how to call paint method

Tags: java, swing

Hi i want to know how to call the paint method...

I am a novice programmer and am really just experimenting with things like paint.

The program i am trying to make is the game where there are 3 rungs and the aim of the game is to move different sized disks from the left/right rung to the right/left rung.

here is my code(no where near finished give me a break):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int amount = 0;

    // get the amount of rectangles to draw to represent disks
    while (amount <= 1 && amount >= 5) {
        System.out.print("Please enter amount of discs to use(less than 7 more than one).");
        amount = scan.nextInt();            
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // draw a certain amount of rectangles in ascending order
    if (amount <= 1 && amount >= 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            g.fillRect(220 - (20 * i), 200 + (10 * i), 100 - (20 * i), 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In what class is this enclosed? `JFrame`?

Answer (score 4):

The paint method will be called for the first time upon creation of the object.

To force the `paint()` method to be called again you can either call `update(Graphics g)` if you want to pass in a new `Graphics` object, but normally I would suggest using `repaint()` method, since this way it will be scheduled to be called asap.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call it. Instead, you should use the main loop which Java creates for you.

The usual approach is to extend `JPanel` (see this question: [How to make canvas with Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776180/how-to-make-canvas-with-swing)) and override the `paint()` method.

Now create a `JFrame`, add the new UI component to it and open the frame. Java will then make sure it gets rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert or something else to teach others but you need to put your code to be painted to `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method instead of paint and then call repaint method.