# Invisible objects because repaint method - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, repaint

The problem comes because I overwrite the paintComponent method of a jPanel, so when I repaint all the objets are hidden till I focus them. 
I need to overwrite the paintComponent method cause it's the only one answer I'd found in internet to change the background image of a jFrame.

So firstly I create a jPanel class:

```
    public class JPanelFondoPrincipal extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public JPanelFondoPrincipal(){    
        this.setSize(800,500);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension tamanio = getSize();
        ImageIcon imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/fondo_principal.png"));        
        g.drawImage(imagenFondo.getImage(),0,0,tamanio.width, tamanio.height, null);        
        setOpaque(false);
    }
}
```

And in my jPanelForm:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JPanelFondo p = new JPanelFondo();
    this.add(p);
    validate();
    p.repaint();
}
```

I'd already tried to add all my Objets (labels, textFields...) to a new Panel so I can add it after repaint, and set all the objets visibles manually but everything is still invisible.

Many thanks, I need to finish the app in 6 days and I'm getting crazy by the minute

---

**EDIT: SOLVED THANKS TO CARDLAYOUT**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- don't `add` / `remove` `JPanels` or its contents on runtime, use [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead
- your `JPanelFondo p = new JPanelFondo();` doesn't corresponding somehow with `public class JPanelFondoPrincipal extends javax.swing.JPanel {`
- for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/),

Comment: Ok finally I solved it with CardLayout. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

*Swing programs should override paintComponent() instead of overriding paint().*

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/

And you should call `super.paintComponent(g);` first in overriden paintComponent();

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Dimension tamanio = getSize();
        ImageIcon imagenFondo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/fondo_principal.png"));        
        g.drawImage(imagenFondo.getImage(),0,0,tamanio.width, tamanio.height, null);        
        setOpaque(false);
    }
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776180/how-to-make-canvas-with-swing) the proper way to handle painting onto JPanel component.

Comment: Thank you but after changing both things it still doesn't work :(
Question code edited