# Handling Images in Java , Not Label

Tags: java, image, swing, picturebox, javax.imageio

I would like to know the best way for handling the images in Java.
Till now i am doing so using `ImageIcon` of `JLabel` but i dont find the approach right as label does not has `stretch` property like an `vb6 imagebox` which automatically stretch the image to fit the container ..

Please tell me the best way .. Also mention any external library or component i can install for same . I would prefer a free library..

Also i tried `swingfx` library but it was not good enough

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: I am using Same function but it kills the Quality of Images .

Comment: Did you check the second link?

Comment: You could also consider taking a look [imgscalr – Java Image Scaling Library](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)

Comment: Thanks , downloading the library , i love keeping libraries in my collection .. Do u have any library related to pictures/images? i mean picture/image box?

Comment: Not really, wrote most of my own

Answer (score 1):

the simple answer is you can just create a subclass of JPanel (or Canvas if you're working in awt) and in the paintComponent method (paint in the awt world), draw the image doing any scaling/skewing/translation you want.

[How to make canvas with Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776180/how-to-make-canvas-with-swing)