# Draw and redraw on a canvas in swing

Tags: java, swing, canvas

I know there's no direct replacement for `java.awt.Canvas` in swing, and I know [I'm supposed to use a JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776180/how-to-make-canvas-with-swing) and override `paintComponent`, for example like so:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawOval(0, 0, 100, 100);
}
```

And this would draw a black circle on the JPanel when it is created. The problem I have is that I want a dynamic canvas: I want to be able to draw things in response to user input, and redraw continuously, not just once when the application starts. An example would be having a moving object on a canvas, that would need to be redrawn at a rate of say 60 frames per second. How could I achieve this without using AWT components?

EDIT: what I mean is, in an actual canvas, I'd be able to arbitrarily call, say, `drawOval` anywhere in my code, and that would draw an oval on the canvas; is this doable with JPanel?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson that would apply if I were asking "I'm trying to do X but my code is doing Y and I don't know why", whereas my question is "how do I even begin to do X?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
public class Renderer extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    private int x;        

    public Renderer() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, this);
        timer.start();
        x = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        // drawing code
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(x, 0, 100, 100);
    }

    private void update() {
        this.x++;    
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        update();
        repaint();      
    }
```

}

Now just add this to your component (JPanel or whatever):

```
comp.add(new Renderer());
```

Comment: Where is `repaint` defined? Can you give me an example?

Comment: in JComponent which Renderer inherits from. Example of what?

Comment: An example of, say, painting a moving object, based on external variables such as `x` and `y` co-ordinates

Comment: Not what the question is asking, but okay.

Comment: `repaint` calls `paint` (among other things), right?

Comment: Also what I meant was, in an actual canvas, I'd be able to arbitrarily call, say, `drawOval` anywhere in my code, and that would draw an oval on the canvas; is this doable with JPanel?

Comment: it does call paint() over and over. You want your drawing to happen in paint()

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g)` Don't override the `paint(..)` method for any `JComponent`. It should be `paintComponent(..)` as seen above.

Comment: Yep my bad, this should be paintComponent()

Comment: @Sam do you mean to call `super.paintComponent(g)` rather than `super.paint(g)`?

Answer (score 3):

Store the information to be drawn (e.g. a `Shape` or a group of them) and call `repaint()` from a Swing `Timer`. Each time the `paintComponent(..)` method is called, first call the `super(..)` method to erase the previous drawings, then iterate the list of shapes, move them if necessary, and draw each one.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason that swing doesn't have Canvas from AWT? It seems like a silly thing to omit...